# Why sync parameter expect two array to be pass using multiple model?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Can somebody explained me why I need to pass two closed array `[[]]` in my sync parameter? I tried to use one array with multiple model inside and it's not syncing. I tried two array and it works. Any tips would appreciated!

```
$document = new Document();
foreach($request->recipient as $recipientId)
{
  $document->notifications()->sync([['user_id' => $recipientId, 'sender_id' => $user->id, 'notification_id' => 4]],false);
}
```

Comment: Show more information abouts your objects

Comment: @KmasterYC I have a `document` object of my Model.

Answer (score 1):

Simply the `sync` method expects an array of id for the models to attach, and any other pivot changes in the second array.
Please check below the example from the documentation:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out more on what the sync method expects in the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships.

At its most basic level, the sync method accepts an array of ids.
You can also sync an array of arrays where each child array contains intermediate table values, which is what you are doing. You are only syncing one item though, thus the double brackets.